# Antd Modal how to update the value in it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I'm using Antd Modal to display order information by passing props to TableDetail Component. The thing is when I try to remove the items in the order I use setState and the modal won't update its data.

https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-reproduction-template-forked-vu3ez
A simple version of reproduction is provided above.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SP6MH.png)
After I click on the remove button the items remain unchanged but when I close and open the modal it will update.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiZrE.png)

What should I do to make it change? I tried forceUpdate() but it won't work.

Here is the TableDetail component.

```
export default class TableDetail extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tableOrder: props.tableOrder,
      column: []
    };
  }

  tableInitializer = () => {
    const column = [
      {
        title: "name",
        render: (item) => {
          return <span>{item.name}</span>;
        }
      },
      {
        title: "price",
        render: (item) => {
          return item.price;
        }
      },
      {
        title: "amount",
        render: (item) => {
          return <span>{item.amount}</span>;
        }
      },
      {
        title: "removeButton",
        render: (item) => {
          return (
            <Button
              type="link"
              style={{ color: "red" }}
              onClick={() => this.props.removeItem(item)}
            >
              Remove
            </Button>
          );
        }
      }
    ];
    this.setState({
      column
    });
  };

  UNSAFE_componentWillMount() {
    this.tableInitializer();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Modal
        visible={true}
        title={
          <span style={{ fontSize: "1.5rem", fontWeight: "bold" }}>
            Table: {this.state.tableName}
          </span>
        }
        cancelText="Cancel"
        okText="OK"
        onCancel={this.props.hideModal}
      >
        <Table
          columns={this.state.column}
          dataSource={this.state.tableOrder}
          rowKey="name"
        />
      </Modal>
    );
  }
}

TableDetail.propTypes = {
  tableOrder: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  tableName: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  hideModal: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  removeItem: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `filter` method in your `removeItem` function

```
  removeItem = (item) => {
    const filtered = this.state.tableOrder.filter(
      (order) => item.name !== order.name
    );
    console.log(item, filtered);
    this.setState({
      tableOrder: filtered
    });
  };
```

and one more thing you should avoid assigning your props to state like

```
   this.state = {
      tableOrder: props.tableOrder,
    };
```

instead of assigning to state directly use that as props like

```
     <Table
      dataSource={this.props.tableOrder}
     />
```

> In most cases, this is an antipattern. Don’t “copy props into state.”
> It creates a second source of truth for your data, which usually leads
> to bugs. One source of truth is best.

Improved code [Live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-reproduction-template-forked-tltuw?file=/table-detail.js)

Answer (score 1):

The issue in your code is in `removeItem`. You are trying to mutate tableOrder. According to [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

> Never mutate this.state directly, as calling setState() afterwards may replace the mutation you made. Treat this.state as if it were *immutable*

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this method can potentially return the existing value.

So that is why it is kind of asynchronous and you can't see your updated changes. You need to do this:

```
removeItem = (item) => {
    const { tableOrder } = this.state;
    const newTable = [...tableOrder]; <- Create new variable and update variable
    for (let i = 0; i < newTable.length; i++) {
      if (item.name === newTable[i].name) {
        console.log("Got it! " + newTable[i].name);
        newTable.splice(i, 1);
        console.log("new table: ", tableOrder);
        break;
      }
    }
    this.setState({
      tableOrder: newTable <- update here
    });
  };
```

You dont need to actually modify array you can simply do this also:

```
this.setState(
{
tableOrder: this.state.tableOrder.filter(data => !(data.name===item.name))
}
)
//filter creates new array
```

Here is demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-reproduction-template-forked-j4bfl?file=/tables.js